# Java Vector : Secure reference to element

Tags: java, java-me, vector

Coming from a C# Background I never used any pointers.

I'm creating a vector of contacts objects. What is the best way to create a separate vector which references to elements in the big vector?

Comment: Its practically the same concept as in C#. What security do you wish?

Comment: I have an application with contains a vector with about 1000 Contact Objects (names, adresses etc) but now I want to create a favorites vector but don't want to copy the entire object to the new favorites vector but instead using a reference. So I only have to update the big vector and the favorites vector get updated too.

Comment: Just a note: Vector in java is something of a relic. It's synchronized so there's a bit of a performance overhead using Vector vs. using other List implementations

Comment: Secure in the way that when I i.e. resort the big vector the reference shouldn't point to the wrong element.

Comment: My answer will do just what you intend.

Comment: wds: There's a little bit of a problem with Java ME implementation tending to be a little light weight on the library implementation side. Got save that fraction of a cent worth of flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the old `Vector` and add the elements to a new `Vector`.

```
Vector oldVector;
Vector newVector = new Vector(oldVector.size());

for (int i = 0; i < oldVector.size(); i++){
    // add logic to exclude items from the new vector if you need
    newVector.add(oldVector.get(i));
}
```

Now, both vectors contain references to the same objects.  Calling:

```
newVector.get(n).modifyInSomeWay();
```

The change will be reflected in both lists.

Comment: I don't want to copy elements.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood the concept of a Vector. A Vector always contains references?!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same object *reference* to both Vectors!

```
Contact myContact = getContact();

Vector vectorOne = new Vector();
Vector vectorTwo = new Vector();

vectorOne.add(myContact);
vectorTwo.add(myContact);
```

There is only one instance of `myContact`, but *many* references to it.